# Need a web API action method to implement removeUrl of kendo angular upload component

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, kendo-ui-angular2

I need a full working example for implementing the remove functionality in telerik kendo angular with Angular 8 and a backend web API in ASP.net core 2.2

In kendo Angular I'm trying to implement the functionality of upload files and removing it when user clicks the x small buttons
I've already implemented the upload so perfectly but when providing the removeUrl it gives error 404 or 415

The other strange thing is when I provide the same url for the upload and download it binds and code could go well but i need a separate action for the remove functionality

```
    [HttpPost("upload"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFileCollection files)
    {
          long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
          //var reqFiles = Request.Form.Files;
          var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
          if (!Directory.Exists(uploads))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploads);
                }

                List<string> paths = new List<string>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                        paths.Add(filePath);
                    }
                }

                // process uploaded files
                // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

                return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, paths });
            }
```

and for delete

```
    [HttpPost]
    private IActionResult Delete(IList<string> files)
            {
               // var reqFiles = Request.Form.Files;
                var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");

                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, item);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                return Ok(new { files });
            }
```

Error 404 is raised when trying to name the action in web api and provide this name in the url (although the same thing is working when uploadling) and 415 is being raised when using post request without naming the action in the back end
[image: errors logged]

Comment: How did you get the kendo control to send the file to the upload endpoint? I followed their example, but the file never arrives at my endpoint. Can you share some code?

Comment: @JasonSmith I apologize for being too late to respond to your comment.
Well there were two options to handle the files, 1- to only show the file in the control and hold it then in the submit get it from the control and send it as a raw file. 2- Handle the 'saveKendoUrl' and 'removeKendoUrl' in your backend to handle the upload and delete files. You can just make an interceptor to return ok for that if you do not want to make requests like:
if (req.url === 'saveKendoUrl') { const success = of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200 }));
return success;
}